# Trying to incorporate IIF in Select Statement

Tags: ms-access, iif

Trying to incorporate IIF in selecting data from MS Access SQL statement.

If I have two addresses for each person in a DB, with a key telling which one is to be used, how do I tell the SQL statement to use address 1 or address 2 based on that key? This is to create a query which can be used in a report.

I've tried this but it throws an error at the first IIF:

```
SELECT MAILINGTABLE.MailAutoNumber, MAILINGTABLE.MailLastName, MAILINGTABLE.MailFirstName, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=1) MAILINGTABLE.MailAddr1 as AD1, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=1) MAILINGTABLE.MailAddr2 as AD2, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=1) MAILINGTABLE.MailCity as city, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=1) MAILINGTABLE.MailState as State, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=1 MAILINGTABLE.MailZip as Zip, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=2) MAILINGTABLE.Addr2Addr1 as AD1,
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=2) MAILINGTABLE.Addr2Addr2 as AD2, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=2) MAILINGTABLE.Addr2City as City, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=2) MAILINGTABLE.Addr2State as State, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2=2) MAILINGTABLE.Addr2Zip as Zip, 
  MAILINGTABLE.MailSalutation, MAILINGTABLE.[232HelpFundraiser], 
  MAILINGTABLE.InformalSalutation, MAILINGTABLE.[232HelpFundraiser1or2]
FROM MAILINGTABLE
WHERE (((MAILINGTABLE.[232HelpFundraiser])=Yes))
ORDER BY MAILINGTABLE.MailLastName, MAILINGTABLE.MailFirstName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The IIf() syntax is all wrong. Should be like:
`IIf(this condition true, use this field, else use other field)`
You would need 5 of these expressions if you want to make this determination for each address line individually.

Otherwise suggestion for a single IIf():

```
IIf(MailNewsletter1or2 = 1, MailAddr1 & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &  MailAddr2 & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & MailCity & ", " & MailState & " " & MailZip,  
Addr2Addr1 & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Addr2Addr2 & Chr(13) & Chr(10) Addr2City & ", " & Addr2State & " " & Addr2Zip) AS Address
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The first IIF got a syntax error:SELECT MAILINGTABLE.MailAutoNumber, MAILINGTABLE.MailLastName, MAILINGTABLE.MailFirstName, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2 = 1  MAILINGTABLE.MailAddr1, MailingTable.Addr2Addr1) as Ad1, 
  IIF(MailNewsletter1or2 = 1 MAILINGTABLE.MailAddr2, MailingTable.Addr2Addr2) as Ad2,
etc.

Comment: I found the syntax error.  It does seem to work, thanks.